# iOS 10.3 cannot open sqlite db

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

The app saves data in a lot of different categories, each category has its own db.
When you switch between categories you close / open a new db.

Problem:
Some of these db's cannot be opened by sqlite, others are working as expected using the exact same code.

Also, this problem started after the latest update (iOS 10.3).

Get path to file:

```
    -(NSString *) filePath {
    NSString *appGroupId = @"xxx.xxx.extension";
    NSURL *appGroupDirectoryPath = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:appGroupId];
    NSURL *dataBaseURL = [appGroupDirectoryPath  URLByAppendingPathComponent:_detailItem];
    NSString *paths = dataBaseURL.path;   
 return paths;
}
```

Open DB:

```
-(void)openDB {
    if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &db) != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSLog(@"error");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Opened");
    }
}
```

All db's are opened using this code, only difference is the filenames.
Most of the filenames contain special characters, such as å ä ö.

```
Filenames/DB Names:
ma värd
ga väg A4
```

-Both these files exists in the same folder.

-Both files contains data, some columns are even identical.

-Both are created with same code

When trying to access the first one i get an empty DB file, all SELECT statements returns "no such table: table_name"

When trying to access the second one, everything works as expected.

One of many SELECT statements:

```
-(NSString *)antalAsString:(NSString *)typAvAntal {

    NSString *antalMatt = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT sum(antal) FROM '%@'", typAvAntal];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    NSLog(@"sql string: %@", sql);

    const char *err;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, &err)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
            char *antal = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
            if (antal != NULL) {
                antalMatt = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:antal];

                //....


                }
            }

        }

    else {
        NSLog(@"error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    return antalMatt;
}
```

How is this possible? Did something in sqlite change with iOS 10.3?

EDIT/UPDATE:

Looked through every file in the folder, with NSArray/NSLog, and saw that every filename containing special characters have been duplicated into another format.

These 2 files:

```
Filenames/DB Names:
ma värd
ga väg A4
```

Have become these 4 files:

```
 ma va\U0308rd
 ma v\U00e4rd

 ga va\U0308g A4
 ga v\U00e4g A4
```

When I try to check the file size of "ma va\U0308rd", the string is converted into "ma värd" and so I'm not sure which of the two is referenced.

```
NSString *sourcePath = [self filePath];

NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *Error = nil;
NSArray *sourceFiles = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:sourcePath error:&Error];
int i = 0;
for (NSString *currentFile in sourceFiles)
{
    if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:[sourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[sourceFiles objectAtIndex:i]]])
    {
        if ([currentFile hasPrefix:@"ma"])
        {

        unsigned long long fileSize = [[fm attributesOfItemAtPath:[sourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[sourceFiles objectAtIndex:i]] error:nil] fileSize];

            NSLog(@"FILE: %@ _______ SIZE: %llu", [sourceFiles objectAtIndex:i], fileSize);
        }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"NO FILE EXISTS: %@", currentFile);

    }
    i = i+1;
}
```

A lot of questions:

Why did the update create duplicates?

Which one does the filemanager pick?

Which one does Sqlite pick?

Is there a way to declare "ma va\U0308rd" as NSString without it being converted to "ma värd"?

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Most probably it's because of [APFS](https://9to5mac.com/2017/03/21/what-is-apples-upcoming-apfs-apple-file-system-and-what-it-means-to-you/) introduced in iOS 10.3

Comment: Yes you are probably right, the files seems to be completely out of reach and unable to backup. Will have to delete the entire folder with all data being lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why the update created duplicates of every file in the app groups folder. 
But learned that there is a way to control which unicode form is used with special characters. It seems that if not specified, the system either picks one at random or chooses the first file it finds, no matter which form is has.

Apple documentation:

```
> decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping A string made by normalizing the
> string’s contents using the Unicode Normalization Form D.
> 
> decomposedStringWithCompatibilityMapping A string made by normalizing
> the receiver’s contents using the Unicode Normalization Form KD.
> 
> precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping A string made by normalizing the
> string’s contents using the Unicode Normalization Form C.
> 
> precomposedStringWithCompatibilityMapping A string made by normalizing
> the receiver’s contents using the Unicode Normalization Form KC.
```

decomposed - uses sequences of characters (a + \U0308 = ä)

precomposed - uses unique code for each character (\U00e4 = ä)

Was able to save all data by switching between these to access the real db files and delete the "dummies" that was created.

```
-(NSString *) filePath {
        NSString *appGroupId = @"xxx.xxx.extension";
        NSURL *appGroupDirectoryPath = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:appGroupId];
        NSURL *dataBaseURL = [appGroupDirectoryPath  URLByAppendingPathComponent:_detailItem];
        NSString *paths = dataBaseURL.path.decomposedStringWithCompatibilityMapping;

     return paths;
    }
```